# Jquery: How to get variable local outside function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little problem how to take the variable "j" and print it outside the function.
The variable "j" is located in a for loop that counts the number of input, I want to take this variable outside this entire function. Please help

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    if (i == i) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 1;
    }
    $('#addScnt').live('click', function korzen() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="id' + i + '" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;

            for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                //-----"j" this varible otuside function
            }
            return false;

        }
    );

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;

            for (var j = i; j >= i; j--) {
                document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = j - 1;
            };

        }
        return false;
    });
});

document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = j;
```

Comment: Define `var j` outside the `live` handler function.

Comment: Format your code properly before posting it. In fact, if you want your code to be a little maintainable, format it before to commit it...

Comment: Can you not just set it inside your function?  And as a side note, what is the point of your if (i == i) { line?

Answer (score 0):

I have did some changes in your code...

```
var j = 0;

$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    if (i == i) {
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = 1;
    }
    $('#addScnt').live('click', function korzen() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="id' + i + '" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;

            for (j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                //-----"j" this varible otuside function
            }
            return false;

        }
    );

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;

            for (j = i; j >= i; j--) {
                document.getElementById("distance_road").innerHTML = j - 1;
            };

        }
        return false;
    });
});

document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype of what you have:

```
(function() {
    for(var i=0; i<10;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
})();
console.log("i: "+i);
```

leads to: `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`

remove the `var` in the for-loop and you have a global variable:

```
(function() {
    for(i=0; i<10;i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
})();
console.log("i: "+i);
```

also check it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7t8Xy/

**Additional note:**

- When you use global variables use a prefix on your variables. The chance that some other code also uses `j` as variablename is big. I try to prevent global variables. But if I have to I use a prefix like the project name or company name. In your case maybe just `my_j`.
- Use a good name for global variables. `i` or `j` in a for-loop is ok. But as a gloabal variable it's not ok. 2000 lines away from this for-loop noone knows what `j` represents. Use a name that descriptes the variable. In your case - I am not sure what j stands for, its just a guess - maybe `my_maxDistanceRoad`.